# iOS NSDate Comparison works differently when the 24-Hour Time in date settings toggles between ON and OFF?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Team,
I am comparing the date which is formed from string using NSDateFormatter with the iOS system date. The below statement returns true when the system date time settings is set with 24-Hour Time ON, but the same code returns false when 24-Hour Time OFF.

**Problematic Code:**

```
if ([(NSDate*)[NSDate date] compare:currDate] == NSOrderedAscending) {
     // -- Code -- This is executed only when the 4-Hour Time ON
 }
```

I am confused. The string using which I am getting the date is in 24 hours format. Is this a problem? Or anything else?

**Date Formatting Code:**

```
-(NSDate *)getDateFromString:(NSString *)dateString{
    NSDateFormatter* fmt = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [fmt setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss"];
    [fmt setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
    [fmt setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehaviorDefault];  
    return [fmt dateFromString:dateString];
}
```

Comment: You can check the time format and perfrom ?

Comment: Where does `dateString` come from? Show us an example of its value when the iOS device is in 24-hour mode and when the iOS device is in 12-hour mode.

Comment: Side notes: 1) Why do you cast `[NSDate date]`? It is already an `NSDate *`. 2) No need to set the date formatter's timezone. It already defaults to the current timezone. 3) No need to set the formatter's behavior. It defaults to "BehaviorDefault".

Comment: @rmaddy This is the sample date string 23 May 2013 15:37:00. This comes from a service.

Comment: Just to rule it out. In the formatter Can you change hh for HH?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See Apple's [Technical Q&A 1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1480/_index.html).

You need to set the date formatter's locale to the special locale of `en_US_POSIX`. You also need to specify a 24-hour hour format - `HH`, not `hh`.

```
-(NSDate *)getDateFromString:(NSString *)dateString{
    NSLocale *posix = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
    NSDateFormatter* fmt = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [fmt setLocale:posix];
    [fmt setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"];

    return [fmt dateFromString:dateString];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion HH works for me... But why I want to add NSLocale stuffs? Even without that its working. Could you please reason out when it will break if we are not adding NSLocale?

Comment: @EaswaramoorthyKanagaraj: He provided a link to the Apple document which explains why.  Go read that and you will understand why you need to change the locale.

Answer (score 1):

**`23 May 2013 15:37:00`** is a 24 hour format string.So the correct date is obtained using the 24 hour format date formatter .Thats it

So use

```
[fmt setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
```

Comment: It's more than this. See [Technical Q&A 1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1480/_index.html).

Comment: This works for me ! Thanks since @rmaddy 's answer has more information accepting his answer !