# DateFormatter doesn't return date for "HH:mm:ss"

Tags: ios, swift, date, swift3

Here is the code excerpt:

```
func mapping(map: Map) {
    time      <- (map["time"], TransformOf<Date, String>(fromJSON: {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
        //dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "EEST")
        if let argument = $0 {
            let date = dateFormatter.date(from: argument)
            return dateFormatter.date(from: argument)
        }
        return nil
        }}
```

`$0` is string with `"22:12:00"`. I put "let date" to see what it returns and it's nil. I've looked up for format codes here: http://waracle.net/iphone-nsdateformatter-date-formatting-table/

Code should work actually. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**: Added the whole function

**EDIT2**: I just noticed it's working properly on iPhone 7 iOS 10.1 simulator but returns nil on my iPod 10.1.1 (2016). This is so weird.

Comment: You probably have to set the formatters locale to "en_US_POSIX", see for example http://stackoverflow.com/a/16706425/1187415 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/25671175/1187415 .

Comment: The app will not be used in US and even if that's the case I don't want it to be localized for en_US. Also I checked settings of simulator and ipod, both are the same.

Comment: @bymafmaf: Did you at least *try* if it makes a difference?

Comment: Off topic: what will I google for if I do not understand this syntax: ` time      <- ( ...`

Comment: @MartinR i tried it worked but returned different value than what simulator normally returns. both UTC, 1 hour forward in device with en_US_POSIX

Comment: @bymafmaf: That is a different issue, printing a `Date` *always* uses UTC.

Comment: @shallowThought it must be user-defined operator

Comment: @ramacode: ahh, that makes sense. Thx! (suspicious to be the root of the issue also)

Comment: @MartinR I added "en_US_POSIX" to everywhere I do formatting. Now it seems to work fine. Please write it as answer so that I can mark it. Thank you!

Comment: @bymafmaf i'm facing same issue of getting nil date for string HH:mm:ss?
Can you suggest any solution for it.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

From [Technical Q&A QA1480 – NSDateFormatter and Internet Dates](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1480/_index.html) (emphasis added):

> On the other hand, if you're working with fixed-format dates, you should **first set the locale of the date formatter to something appropriate for your fixed format.** In most cases the best locale to choose is "en_US_POSIX", a locale that's specifically designed to yield US English results regardless of both user and system preferences.

This will prevent the date from being interpreted according to 
the user's regional settings:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
// Set the locale first ...
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
// ... and then the date format:
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"

// ...
```

See also [What is the best way to deal with the NSDateFormatter locale "feechur"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613110/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-the-nsdateformatter-locale-feature).

Answer (score -1):

sample of usage:

```
let a = Date.now

let b = a.asString("yyyy-MM-dd")
let c = Date.fromString(strDate: "2023-05-30", "yyyy-MM-dd")
```

back code:

```
extension DateFormatter {
    static var shared = getSharedDateFormatter()
    
    fileprivate static func getSharedDateFormatter(template: String? = nil) -> DateFormatter {
        let df = DateFormatter()
        df.timeZone = .current
        df.dateFormat = template ?? "HH:mm:ss"
        
        df.amSymbol = "AM"
        df.pmSymbol = "PM"
        
        return df
    }
}

public extension Date {
    func asString(_ template: String?) -> String {
        DateFormatter.shared.dateFormat = template
        return DateFormatter.shared.string(from: self)
    }
    
    static func fromString(strDate: String, _ template: String) -> Date? {
        DateFormatter.shared.dateFormat = template
        
        return DateFormatter.shared.date(from: strDate)
    }
}
```

important thing:
this code does not create lot of instances of DateFormatter so it's works really fast.