# Sometimes NSTimeZone doesn't return proper UTC value?

Tags: ios, swift, timezone

I have encountered with below lines of code sometimes doesn't return proper UTC value:

```
let date = NSDate()
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"
formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
```

Returns:

```
"2016-12-11 2:07:35 am +0000"
```

Instead of:

```
"2016-12-11 02:07:35 +0000"
```

What's wrong with that?

Comment: Set the date formatter locale to POSIX, compare e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613110/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-the-nsdateformatter-locale-feature or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40692378/swift-3-dateformatter-doesnt-return-date-for-hhmmss.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks I added that posix. What you think using currentLocale() here's an answer below. I think It is not proper, isn't it?

Answer (score -2):

please use these code

```
    let date = NSDate()
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"
    formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
    formatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
    print(formatter.stringFromDate(date))
```

Comment: I think using currentLocale() is not proper thing with UTC, I added posix as "en_US_POSIX" for my above code like Martin said in above comment.

Comment: A date formatter uses the current locale and the local time zone by default.