# Why "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" always return nil when i run app into iPhone 7

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, nsdateformatter, xcode8

I am working on a application where i need to convert a date from string to Date format according to Swift. 
I have write a code for converting String date to Date format and that was working fine when i was checking it on simulator on iPhone 7, 6, 6plus and etc. 
And also working great when i was checking it on iPhone 5s, and 4s. **But** when i try to check my application with iPhone 7 Real device then my application getting crashed on a error.

And The error is :- `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

As i debug my application in iPhone 7 then i am getting problem to convert a string date into Date format.

this the code which is i am using to convert a String date into Date in Swift

```
print("wakeupDateTime=\(wakeupDateTime)")
let dtf = DateFormatter()
dtf.timeZone = TimeZone.autoupdatingCurrent
dtf.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
let defaultStartdate  = dtf.date(from: wakeupDateTime)!
print(defaultStartdate)
```

Here my `wakeupDateTime` is `2016-12-12 11:13:44`

Please help me for that. thanks

Comment: try to set locale identifier with " UTC"  and then see if still return nil then tell me

Comment: @Jecky Yes I did change Timezone with "UTC", and this still return nil

Comment: Wait I will give you one function of date conversion pleases try it. I have also same problem but it solved. So Please check out my answer just one and reply me if it working or not. If its not working then I will delete my answer for others

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40692378/swift-3-dateformatter-doesnt-return-date-for-hhmmss ? Set the date formatter locale to POSIX.