# Dateformatter issue in swift

Tags: ios, swift, date, datetime, nsdateformatter

My API sending me date string in UTC like 2/20/2016 11:45 AM.
For displaying date in my timezone, I am converting date from UTC to Local time zone like below code

```
    let sourceDateString = "12/20/2016 11:45 AM"
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
     formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a"
     formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
     let date = formatter.date(from: sourceDateString)

     print(date)

     formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
     formatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd,yyyy hh:mm a"

     let strDate = formatter.string(from: date!)
     print(strDate)
```

Above code is working fine if my device time format is in 12 HR but if I am using 24 Hr date from my device then above code is not working. Event it's not able to convert UTC string to date.

Please check above code in the device, it's working fine in simulator.

Comment: Use `HH` instead of `hh`, `hh` is for `12` hour format and `HH` is for `24` hour format.

Comment: Set the date formatters locale to "Posix", compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40692378/swift-3-dateformatter-doesnt-return-date-for-hhmmss.

Comment: @MartinR after assigning dateFormatter locale to "POSIX", the format needs to include "HH" instead of "hh" (as mentioned in your answer), right?

Comment: @AhmadF: No, you can also set it to "hh a" *after* fixing the locale. Setting "Posix locale" is done to ignore the user's locale settings.

Comment: @MartinR Ok I got it about the need of changing the locale, but what about that "HH" is the format for 24-hour, how should it works if "hh" is kept as is? sorry for bothering, but I really would like to understand what is going on here :)

Comment: @AhmadF: The question (as I understand it) is about converting a date from UTC to the local time zone, and *not* about 12hr to 24hr conversion.

Comment: @MartinR You are awesome man posix worked. Thanks for help you are genius.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With help of @Martin R, Following code worked for me.

```
    let sourceDateString = "12/20/2016 11:45 AM"
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a"
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    let date = formatter.date(from: sourceDateString)

    print(date)

    formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
    formatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd,yyyy hh:mm a"

    let strDate = formatter.string(from: date!)
    print(strDate)
```

I forgot to add "POSIX".

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix for this is to convert 12hr to 24 hr format.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateformatter.dateFormat = @"hh:mm a";
NSDate *date = [dateformatter dateFromString:departTime];
dateformatter.dateFormat = @"HH:mm";
NSString *time24 = [dateformatter stringFromDate:date];
departTimelbl.text=time24;
```

here you can replace
**formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a"** with **formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm**

Comment: It's not about convert 12hr to 24 hr.

Comment: need to change this piece of code formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a" with formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm

Comment: Nope man by adding following line it worked. formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")

Answer (score 0):

**Code written in Swift 3.0**

You need to give local identifier on date formatter.

Here is the following working and tested code.

```
let sourceDateString = "12/22/2016 09:19 AM"
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a"
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en-US")
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
    let date = formatter.date(from: sourceDateString)

    print("\(date)")

    formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
    formatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd,yyyy hh:mm a"

    let strDate = formatter.string(from: date!)
    print(strDate)
```

Please let me know if it works.

Comment: I need output like Dec 28, 2016 12:30 AM so your code won't work.

Comment: Okay, I have edited my answer, just the timezone identifier was missing...