# Why DateFormatter returns nil?

Tags: ios, swift, date, swift3, nsdate

I have the next string date:

```
"2017-01-04 15:25:37 +0000"
```

and now I want to convert it to `Date` in Swift 3:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2017-01-04 15:25:37 +0000")
```

Why it returns `nil`?

Comment: for me your code works and doesn't return nil

Comment: The code is correct. Not related, but in Swift 3 the time zone init method is `TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")` without any type cast.

Comment: What `Locale` is the device in question? You may want to set the `locale` of the formatter to be `en_US_POSIX`. E.g. `dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")`.

Comment: Possible duplicate  of (e.g.) [Swift 3 DateFormatter doesn't return date for “HH:mm:ss”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40692378/swift-3-dateformatter-doesnt-return-date-for-hhmmss)

Comment: @vadian I replaced that line, but nothing again

Comment: That's why I wrote *not related*

Comment: @vadian yes, I know. Thanks

Comment: @J.Doe: Did you set the `locale` *before* setting the `dateFormat` ?

Comment: @MartinR yes, before

Comment: You might try `X` or `ZZZZZ` instead of `Z`.

Comment: You should also set the date formatter calendar to iso8601