# Date formatter returning nil value

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter, ios10

I have this code working but now all of a sudden, it started crashing. I could not figure it out, any help would be appreciated.

```
 let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
 dateFormat = "EEE, MMM d, yyyy hh:mm a"
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = dateFormat                  
 let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString("Thu, Jan 5, 2017 12:28 PM")
```

It is returning `date` as nil. Why? I want it to return proper date.

This looks like a possible duplicate question, but it is with specific details.

Comment: I tried it and it return the proper date 
`let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
let dateFormat = "EEE, MMM d, yyyy hh:mm a"
dateFormatter.dateFormat = dateFormat
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "Thu, Jan 5, 2017 12:28 PM")`

date is **"Jan 5, 2017, 12:28 PM"**.

Comment: are you using swift 3.0?

Comment: Yes, I'm using swift 3.

Comment: Try setting the formatters locale to "en_US_POSIX", compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/40702569/1187415.

Comment: Btw, your code is Swift 2, it does *not* compile with Swift 3.

Comment: @MartinR I think OP might still be using Swift 2 (he shouldn't be, but I think he is)

Comment: Yes, I am using Swift 2.

Comment: @ImanMustafa then refer my answer

Comment: @BenjaminLowry: Yes. But *"this is how you would do it in Swift 3"* or *"your code works fine for me"* are not answers to the question *"why does my dateformatter return nil"*?

Comment: @MartinR Fair enough. I will delete my answer.

Comment: I think this is an iOS related bug. I had the same issue. It was returning nil on iOS  10.0.2, whereas was returning the right date on other iOSes.

Answer (score 0):

```
let dateformattor = NSDateFormatter()
dateformattor.dateFormat = "EEE, MMM d, yyyy hh:mm a"
dateformattor.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
let dt = "Thu, Jan 5, 2017 12:28 PM"

let dt1 = dateformattor.dateFromString(dt as String)
print(dt1) //print date and time UTC format.
```

Output :

```
2017-01-05 06:58:00 +0000
```

Comment: This is not Swift 3 friendly.

Comment: its swift 2.0 @BenjaminLowry

Comment: My bad, I thought OP was using Swift 3.0.

Comment: @BenjaminLowry if you need for swift 3.0 then i can also convert this simple code in swift 3.0

Comment: Oh no, I've also posted an answer to this question (in swift 3). I just misread the comments and thought the OP was using swift 3.

Comment: @BenjaminLowry its ok. then my answer is correct if you agree then give up vote according to question.

Comment: I could say the same to you ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        let dateFormat = "EEE, MMM d, yyyy hh:mm a"
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = dateFormat
        let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "Thu, Jan 5, 2017 12:28 PM")
```

**OUTPUT :**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Every time you work with time and date formatters remember to set **locale** and **timezone**!

Device with non-english locale will fail to parse "Thu, Jan 5, 2017 12:28 PM" as "Thu" and "Jan" are obviously english specific.

So:

```
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
```

or whatever time zone and locale you want to use