# DateFormatter in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, date, nsdateformatter

So, I have some code in my playground:

```
extension String {
   func stringToDate(withFormat format:String) -> Date? {
      let df = DateFormatter()
      df.dateFormat = format

      return df.date(from: self) ?? nil
   }
}

struct Some { 
   let date:String
}

let some = Some(date: "Fri, 06 Jan 2017 04:36:17 +0000")

print(some.date.stringToDate(withFormat: "E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z") ?? "ooops")
```

And it's work's fine. I received the date that I expected - 2017-01-06 04:36:17 +0000
But in my app same code and same string with date does not work properly

Playground:
[image: Playground]

APP:[image: App]

Comment: "E" is one symbol, and you provide 3 in your code("Fri")

Comment: are you sure there isn't another extension with the same name being called? print something from your extension to make sure it gets called

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/40702569/1187415 – Set the formatters locale to "en_US_POSIX".

Comment: Can you show us how you called test() ? I'm curious why you're getting a nil in your log. It might be how you initialized your Some struct.

Answer (score 2):

You possibly have different default locales in playground and in application.

You can check it with `print(df.locale)`.

E.g. if you set locale to `ru_RU`:

```
df.locale = Locale(identifier: "ru_RU")
```

then your date will not be parsed.

To have stable parsing result set locale to `en_US_POSIX` as @MartinR suggested.