# Localized date from string returns nil

Tags: swift, nsdate

Sometimes when my app parse dates, it returns `nil` and I can't explain it.

I never had the problem by testing on my iPhone, but only one of my users (at the moment) is complaining about that.

I have a class func to parse all dates inside the app which is:

```
class func localizedDate(from string: String) -> NSDate? {
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
    return dateFormatter.dateFromString(string)
}
```

The NSDate I parse are like this: `2017-01-16T16:49:52.581Z`.

And **Yes**, I'm sure that this is the problem, even if that looks so bizarre.
I logged everything and the result is:

```
localizedDate(from: "2017-01-16T16:49:52.581Z") == nil
    // on my client device
localizedDate(from: "2017-01-16T16:49:52.581Z") == 2017-01-16 15:49:52 +0000 (localized)
    // on my iPhone by testing with Xcode
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Try setting the formatter's locale to "en_US_POSIX": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40692378/dateformatter-doesnt-return-date-for-hhmmss.

Comment: Think about the name: `localizedDate`. It's all about that phone's `locale`.