# Swift: DateFormatter not able to parse date

Tags: ios, swift, date, nsdateformatter

I've a specific time format which I want to use to generate a Date object.
This is the format:

```
Fri, 17 Mar 2017 08:42:00 +0100
```

Here is my Swift code that should create the data object:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss xx"
let d = dateFormatter.date(from: value)
```

The generation of the Date object with dateFormatter.date does always return nil. But I cant see what's wrong in my formatting string.
Can anyone see my error?

Comment: Works for me, so it could be locale dependent. Does this help http://stackoverflow.com/a/40702569/1187415 ?

Comment: Fri, 17 Mar 2017 08:42:00 +0100 this is Nsdate or String ?

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya It's a String.

Comment: then your question is that your dateformatter dont create any date ? or its nil right ?

Comment: @MartinR I'll Check that I really think it could be a locale issue. I wrote the code ob a german machine.

Comment: @Fabian i write your code in my machine and its give me date .

Comment: let the_date: String = "Fri, 17 Mar 2017 08:42:00 +0100"
        
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss xx"
let d = dateFormatter.date(from: the_date)
 print(d)

Op : 2017-03-17 07:42:00 +0000

Comment: i write in playground.it's fine not get any nil value @Fabian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have test it and works perfectly.

Could you test this code line to identify you Locale configuration?

```
print(Locale.current.identifier)
```

I only made a little change related to the Optional result that DateFormatter method returns

```
import Foundation

let the_date: String = "Fri, 17 Mar 2017 08:42:00 +0100"

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale.current
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss xx"

if let d = dateFormatter.date(from: the_date)
{
    print(d)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Stating that you cannot reproduce the problem described in the question is not an answer, compare https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277924/1187415.

Comment: Hi @MartinR. Even if you suggest a code change? Should I delete my post? It's my first "described in the question is not an answer" issue :-)