# DateFormatter dateFromString Always Returns nil in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

Due to some reason fail to convert a string to a NSDate.

This is my date converting code:

```
 let kSQLiteDateFormat : String = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss Z"
let dateFormat = [kSQLiteDateFormat,
"dd MM, yyyy",
"MMM-yyyy",
"yyyy-MM-dd",
"yyyy-12",
"yyyy/MM/dd",
"yyyy/mm/dd",
"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z",
"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss K",
"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZ",
"yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm a",
"MM/dd/yyyy",
"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss Z",
"h:mm a",
"hh:mm a",
"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss Z",
"yyyy/MM/dd h:mm a",
"MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a",
"yyyy-MM-dd h:mm a",
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss",
"yyyy/MM/dd h a",
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss","dd MMM, yyyy","dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm", "EEE, MMM dd","MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"]


if let dateString : String = dateString as String? {
        let dateFormatter : DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        for format in dateFormat {

            dateFormatter.dateFormat =  format
            if  let date : NSDate = (dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)! as NSDate) {
                return date
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
```

every time return nil

Comment: whats your date string

Comment: `dateFormat` needs to match the dateString. But there are plenty and plenty of possibilities. You can try the most common, but it doesn't mean it will works. What's `dateString`.

Comment: `dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)` returns a `Date`, not an `NSDate`

Comment: 06/02/2017 03:05:12 PM date string

Comment: The last one `"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"` should have done the trick, at least for this one (could be that month and day are inverted for another date).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The forced unwrapping in

```
if  let date : NSDate = (dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)! as NSDate) {
    return date
}
```

makes the program crash if `dateString` does not match the date format and `dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)` returns `nil`.

What you probably want is

```
if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString) {
    return date
}
```

or, if you really need an `NSDate` and not a `Date`:

```
if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString) {
    return date as NSDate
}
```

In addition, you might want to set the formatter's locate to "POSIX"

```
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
```

in order to avoid a dependency on the user's regional preferences,
compare [DateFormatter doesn't return date for "HH:mm:ss"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40692378/dateformatter-doesnt-return-date-for-hhmmss).

Comment: setting locale fixed the crashes that happened randomly in my apps

Answer (score 4):

I found if you choose to use format like "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss" instead of "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", you will get nil if your hour great than 12. please notice the difference of the hh and HH .

so this format "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss" should work.

Answer (score 0):

From your code it can return nil only in this line

```
return nil
```

and the means that this this check returns false

`if let dateString : String = dateString as String?`

check your `dateString` variable maybe it is nil.

Comment: my detestring is "06/02/2017 03:05:12 PM"

Comment: can you paste here the whole function, full code which you used to get the date?

Comment: class func dateFromString(dateString : String) -> NSDate? {
        if let dateString : String = dateString as String? {
            let dateFormatter : DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            for format in dateFormat {
                
                dateFormatter.dateFormat =  format
                if  let date : NSDate = (dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)! as NSDate) {
                    return date
                }
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

Comment: calling a function NSDate.dateFromString(dateString: dateAssigned)

Comment: Why you are trying to check if dateString is not nil when you dateString parameter not a nullable String?
remove this line 
if let dateString : String = dateString as String? {