# NSDateFormatter doesn't work in IOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

The formatter works normally in iOS 10, but when I run it in iOS 11, it returns nil.

```
let dateString = "2017-09-27 17:29:50"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString) {
    // ...
} else {
    print("error, trying to convert published date: \"\(dateString)\" using \"\(dateFormatter.dateFormat)\"")
}
```

It prints

```
error, trying to convert published date: "2017-09-27 17:29:50" using "Optional("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")"
```

#### Note

I use Xcode 8.3.3 instead of 9 to compile the project.

#### Update

Actually I use Xcode 8.3.3 to compile the project (Swift 3). And distribute it using Diawi. This error doesn't appear in the simulator which makes it really confusing. So to show the error on the device, I tried to show an alert view instead.

This is the alert: 

[image]

Comment: Perhaps this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40692378/dateformatter-doesnt-return-date-for-hhmmss ?

Comment: @Abizern how is this a duplicate question?

Comment: @MartinR thanks, I'll try that.

Comment: @EdwardAnthony The answer should apply.

Comment: @LeoDabus you're right. It works normally if I change the hour time format to 24-hour in the Date & Time Settings.