# NSDate current date returning nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

In some scenario, I am getting `currentDateString` as nil.My app is in live so i can't find out exact scenario.

```
 NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
 NSCalendar *myCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];
 NSString *currentDateString =  [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentDate];
```

Comment: "My app is in live so i can't find out exact scenario." If you have a crash log, you should [symbolicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855389/how-to-symbolicate-crash-log-xcode) it.

Comment: I have no crash log.For server call am passing current date.But for some, the current date is passing as nil.

Comment: check you current date format is coming as different what your expecting.

Comment: Have you tried setting the TimeZone for your formatter? Set it to current TimzeZone.

Comment: i am getting correct result , what the issue u faced

Comment: Yeah, I am getting a correct result too.But in some iPhone from client side we facing that issue.Maybe it may due to phone settings.I tried changing region, calendar type in phone settings but no use.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40692378/dateformatter-doesnt-return-date-for-hhmmss

Comment: Always set the NSLocale of the formatter too

Comment: Please edit the title. It is not `NSDate` returning `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code. I got correct results. Please set DateFormatter Locale

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];
    NSString *currentDateString =  [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentDate];
```