# String did not Convert Properly to Date in ios Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to convert string to date everything is fine but still, it gives me an incorrect date according to string.

**Code:**

```
import UIKit

public class Utils {

    public class func converServerTimeStampToDate (_ timeStamp: String) -> Date {

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy, hh:mm:ss a"

        return dateFormatter.date(from: timeStamp)!
    }
}


print(Utils.converServerTimeStampToDate("12/06/2017, 06:48:03 am"
))
```

**-----OutPut-----**

```
2017-12-06 14:48:03 +0000
```

Comment: why you have tag android and java ?

Comment: you can read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47942040/6822622), this is helpful for you

Comment: date has no proper format , what the OP you expect

Comment: You date it is correct.

Comment: Note that when parsing fixed format dates you should set the date formatter locale to `"en_US_POSIX"`

Comment: java and android can also be helpfull regarding time formatter

Comment: **Fixed-format dates, you should first set the locale of the date formatter to something appropriate for your fixed format. In most cases the best locale to choose is en_US_POSIX, a locale that's specifically designed to yield US English results regardless of both user and system preferences. en_US_POSIX is also invariant in time (if the US, at some point in the future, changes the way it formats dates, en_US will change to reflect the new behavior, but en_US_POSIX will not), and between platforms (en_US_POSIX works the same on iPhone OS as it does on OS X, and as it does on other platforms)**

Comment: What is the timezone of your date string? If your date string it is UTC time you need to set the formatter time zone `dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem set timezone

```
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT+0:00")
```

By default it is taking current time zone that's why your output is different from input.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct result. When you convert any string into `Date` it will convert it in `UTC` timezone. And when you convert that date into string again it will be in your current timezone. So, convert that date into string and you real date you will get. So, your Date object always be in `UTC` timezone and your string will be always in your local timezone. And when you displays your date in label or any other control then definitely you will display in string format and it will be in your local timezone. So, there is nothing wrong in it. You just required to understand the concept!

Comment: You mean when you print the date

Comment: yeah, when we use date to display it to users then we have to first convert it in to string! @LeoDabus

Comment: Note that the result it is correct but his code it isn't. Look at parsing date strings and look at the locale that he should be using https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html

Comment: Another issue he might have it is that the date string that comes from the server it is probably UTC time so he would need to set the date formatter's timezone to zero seconds from GMT

Comment: so can you improve the code i want to get the same time that is in the string

Comment: Is your date string UTC time? just add `dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)`

Comment: don't forget to set the locale `dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")`

Comment: @NasirJaved : convert that date which you get in string with same `dateformatter` and you will get same time string!

Comment: @Lion You are assuming that the string which it is coming from the server it is local time which it is very unlikely

Comment: @LeoDabus : Yeah you are right ! It is unlikely but as questioner asking it seems like that!

Comment: @Lion thats why I didnt post any answer. The question it is unclear :)

Comment: @Lion ok let me check it

Comment: @LeoDabus there are nothing unclear the code is in front of you and the string which i convert is basically the JSON responce from server . all i need is to convert this string into date