# How to Convert date into local time zone ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, date

I'm working on date formatter, I got a response of date from server in string type, which I convert into date format but what I want to do is to convert a date and then manage according to local time.

For example, if `12/06/2017, 06:48:03` is a date from server and i'm from Pakistan so it gives me a date and time according to GMT+5 which is `12/06/2017, 11:48:03`

Same as from India it gives me a date and time according to GMT+5:30 which is `12/06/2017, 12:18:03`

Here is a source code

```
public class func converServerTimeStampToDate (_ timeStamp: String) -> Date {

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy, hh:mm:ss a"
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
        let localDate = dateFormatter.date(from: timeStamp)
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy, hh:mm:ss a"

       // return dateFormatter.string(from: localDate!)
        return dateFormatter.date(from:dateFormatter.string(from: 
       localDate!))!

    }
```

Any help would be appreciated !!

Comment: Read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47942040/6822622) this is helpful for you

Comment: Post your code which you have used to format date

Comment: @MZubairShamshad check the source code

Comment: `dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")` try with gmt timezone and let me know if it fixed

Comment: @MZubairShamshad i tried but still its not working although the i can return the string but not a Date

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want the result to be a Date object just use the first part of @Intellij-Shivam's answer:

```
func serverToLocal(date:String) -> Date? {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
    let localDate = dateFormatter.date(from: date)

    return localDate
}
```

(note that `DateFormatter.date(from:)` returns an optional, which is correct because the input date string might not be in the correct format.)

There is no such thing as a `Date` in your local time zone. `Dates` don't have a time zone. They record an instant in time all over the planet.

To display a date in your local time zone you can use the `DateFormatter` class method `localizedString()`:

```
let dateString = DateFormatter.localizedString(
  inputDate, 
  dateStyle: .medium, 
  timeStyle: .medium)
```

Comment: (I Think you should accept @Intellij-Shivam's answer. The code above is his, with only minor changes.)

Comment: Note that if you're going to make more than occasional use of this code, you should refactor it to create a date formatter once and re-use it. It's fairly expensive to keep creating them and disposing of them. I'd make the above an instance method, and have it use a lazy instance variable for the date formatter.

Answer (score 3):

I hope this will work for your problem

```
func serverToLocal(date:String) -> Date {
 let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
 dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
 let date = dateFormatter.date(from: date)
 dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
 let timeStamp = dateFormatter.string(from: date!)

 return date
}
```

Comment: you can change the `dateFormat` according to the format that you are getting the date and time

Comment: Force unwrapping the output of a dateformatter is a bad idea in a function which accepts the date format as an input argument. Either make your function throwable or return nil if either format is wrong.

Comment: i know for random dateFormat it is not good idea but if the know the dateFormat which we are going to get, i don't think there is no harm in it to forceWrap the return value, if we know the exact date format that we are going to get.

Comment: @Intellij-Shivam yeah its working but i want to return a Date not String

Comment: this will convert you local time zone Date String to Date format @NasirJaved

Comment: You said you wanted a date in your local time zone. A Date object does not have ANY Time zone. If you just change Intellij's function above so that it returns localDate that will give you the server date, but if you try to display it it will be displayed in UTC. You will need to use a local date formatter to display the date in your time zone.

Comment: you can change the format of the date accordingly i have take the standard date format

Comment: error Occur in local date "Cannot convert value of type 'Date?' to expected argument type"

Comment: its because of the format that you are giving is wrong.. and @DuncanC is right you need to use a local date formatter to display the date in your time zone.. this is what i have done in new edii

Comment: @Intellij-Shivam i m posting the code

Comment: @Intellij-Shivam check the code still its not working

Comment: As we said, just use localDate. See my answer.

Comment: yes its Working Thanks Alot

Comment: please accept the answer and upvote it @NasirJaved

Comment: (Sorry Intellij. He ended up accepting my answer instead, even though it was based on your code and I credited you for it. I didn't mean to steal your thunder.) I up-voted your answer though, since it converted the date "into local time" as the OP asked.

Comment: no problem sir I really appreciate that happy to help @DuncanC

Comment: WHy does DateFormatter only accept a string? Why not a date object as param?