# Swift - Convert string to date

Tags: ios, swift, date, dateformatter

On iOS 11+ only, I have this bug : When user has disabled 24h mode in phone hour settings, my string can't be parse to date using this code.

On other iOS version, there is no problems...

Is something missing to force 24h mode for the formatter ?

Variables `date` and `beginHour` came from webservice.

```
// input date = 20171201
// input beginHour = 2359

let dateTimeFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "fr_FR")
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.autoupdatingCurrent
dateTimeFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd HHmm"

if let date = dateTimeFormatter.date(from: date+" "+beginHour) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Most probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40692378/dateformatter-doesnt-return-date-for-hhmmss  – set the formatters locale to "en_US_POSIX" when parsing fixed-format strings.

Comment: Already tried, do not works.

Comment: That is strange. Can you show your updated code? (And please copy your *real* code, there is an inconsistency "dateTimeFormatter" vs "dateFormatter" in the question.)

Comment: it working in 11.0.3 : tested in 24hrs disable mode  let dateTimeFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateTimeFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "fr_FR")
    dateTimeFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.autoupdatingCurrent
    dateTimeFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd HHmm"
    
    if let date = dateTimeFormatter.date(from: "20171201"+" "+"2359") {
        print(date)
    }                 output: 2017-12-01 18:29:00 +0000

Comment: That was a variable name error... Thank you @Martin R

Comment: try this Post:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/47942040/6822622

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your code, you are not using the right dateFormatter, 
kindly check between dateTimeFormatter and dateFormatter,

```
let dateTimeFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateTimeFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "fr_FR")
dateTimeFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.autoupdatingCurrent
dateTimeFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd HHmm"

if let date = dateTimeFormatter.date(from: date+" "+beginHour) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Which 'dateTimeFormatter' are you talking about . Can you explain ??

Comment: in his code, he might have misspelled the dateFormatter, in the very first line he is using dateTimeFormatter and in 2 and 3 he is using dateFormatter

Comment: Yes and no errors because before this code, I have a variable named dateFormatter...