# DateFormatter returns nil on specific devices

Tags: swift, date, dateformatter

I use the following code to convert a string into a date:

```
// Input is "06-10-18, 01:30 pm"

func convertStringToDate(string: String) -> Date {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy, hh:mm a"
    return formatter.date(from: string)!
}
```

This works fine on simulators and my devices, however it crashes on return for a couple of client devices.

I tried seeing what was wrong by making it return a string from a date, and on the client devices it returns this:

```
"06-10-18, 13:30"
```

Why is it returning differently on a handful of devices?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40692378/dateformatter-doesnt-return-date-for-hhmmss/ : set the formatter‘s locale to Posix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The returned date is correct, you can check that using the `.timeIntervalSince1970` property. What happens is that when you print the date (which is actually just a TimeInterval, aka Double, a *specific point in time, independent of any calendar or time zone*), it's printing its [description](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/1779759-description) property, with the current device settings.

To print a date using your current locale, use [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/1780034-description) instance method:

```
let date = convertStringToDate(string: "06-10-18, 01:30 pm")
print(date.description(with: Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")))
```

Comment: Would this also apply using 'en_GB' and other locales?

Comment: Yes of course, you choose the locale. It would only change the string representing the date. But as a `Date`, it is still the same number (timeIntervalSince1970)