# Date format ( "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss VV") returns nil

Tags: swift, date, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to change format my date for in-app purchases but returns nil in real devices but in simulator it working great.

```
let DateString = "2016-01-21 00:29:09 Etc/GMT"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss VV"
var dateObject = dateFormatter.date(from: DateString)
print(dateObject)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always set the `locale` of your `DateFormatter` when dealing with hardcoded Date formats. You can use `en_US_POSIX` in most scenarios.

```
let dateString = "2016-01-21 00:29:09 Etc/GMT"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss VV"
let dateObject = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
print(dateObject)
```

Comment: The locale should be set first, compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/40702569/1187415.

Comment: I'm using it in in-app purchases, so will it effect user living another country or something ?

Comment: @SadiHakanKoşanoğlu no, since the date format used by IAP is fixed regardless of the user's locale.

Answer (score 0):

I solved like this. maybe it's helps

```
 formatter.amSymbol = "AM"
 formatter.pmSymbol = "PM"
```