# DateFormatter with AM/PM returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter, dateformatter

I know that this topic is fully discussed here and in other forums. 
Unfortunately, I still cannot understand why the Date is nil.

Note that when I run the code in the Debugger or in Playground then it works totally fine.
It's something to do with the fact that it runs on the device.

```
   var dateString = "2019-12-17 3:48:02 PM"
   let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
   dateFormatter.locale = Locale.current
   dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
   dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a"
   let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString) // date is nil
```

Comment: The 12 hour format is hh, not HH. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/40692378/1187415

Comment: Try setting Locale to something that you know supports AM/PM, like "en_US_POSIX" or "en_GB" etc

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys, @MartinR I actually tried it with both HH and hh but it didn't work. I set it up to hh anyway since I'm using 12-hour clock.

Answer (score 1):

Add en_US as your Locale, like this:

```
dateFormatter.locale =  NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US")
```