# Data Format is returning nil for this format "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ"

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Well, I have this specific raw string returning from backend which is a date string `"2020-05-27T23:59:59.000+02:00"`

I am trying to format the string using the following code:-

```
 let passExpiresAtString =  "2020-05-27T23:59:59.000+02:00"
 let df = DateFormatter()
 df.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
 df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ"
 session.passExpiresAt = df.date(from: passExpiresAtString)
```

So, I will be glad if anyone can pin me, what I am doing wrong with the date format settings.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It works for me, which means that you probably have to set the locale of the formatter to "en_US_POSIX" (compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/40702569/1187415)

Comment: @MartinR I tied using locale ` df.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")` , seems like it is still returning nil on my device.

Comment: Did you assign the locale  first, *before* assigning the date format?

Comment: Yes, I have also updated the code in question. @MartinR

Comment: The code above works for me. Which swift version are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively set the calendar of the formatter to an ISO8601 calendar

```
let passExpiresAtString =  "2020-05-27T23:59:59.000+02:00"
let df = DateFormatter()
df.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ"
session.passExpiresAt = df.date(from: passExpiresAtString)
```

or – still more reliable – use `ISO8601DateFormatter`

```
let passExpiresAtString =  "2020-05-27T23:59:59.000+02:00"
let df = ISO8601DateFormatter()
df.formatOptions = [.withInternetDateTime, .withFractionalSeconds]
session.passExpiresAt = df.date(from: passExpiresAtString)
```