# NSDateFormatter.dateFromString returns nil when changing phone settings

Tags: objective-c, nsdateformatter, date-format, date-formatting

I am trying to convert a string into Date in iOS (Swift/Objective C) but I have an issue when the date contains the hours in 24 formats like `2018-11-24_18-11-10`

The issue is that when the phone uses 24H option (Setting -> General -> Date & Time) the code works properly but if I disabled this option in the phone the code returns nil

Here is the code in Objective C

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss"];
return [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

and here is it in Swift

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss"
formatter.date(from: dateString)
```

I tried different formats but in the end, I always get nil if the phone does not enable 24H option in the settings

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/40692378/1187415 to me.

Comment: Thanks @MartinR. I tried to set the Locale and it worked in both cases, `dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")`