# DateFormatter returns nil on iPhone, but not on simulator

Tags: ios, swift, dateformatter

I have noticed a weird situation regarding the DateFormatter on iOS 11.3. I am trying to convert a String to a Date using the following code:

```
    let dateString = "2018-05-31 11:45:24Z"
    let dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'Z'"

    var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = dateFormat
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")

    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
```

What is weird is that on simulator it works, but on my iPhone it does not(date is nil).
From what I have noticed, the locale of the dateFormatter on the simulator is en_US and on my iPhone it is en_RO.

If I explicitly set the Locale of the DateFormatter to en_US, it returns the correct value.

```
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en-US")
```

What is more, after I changed my phone's region to United States, it returned correctly and it works even after I changed it back to Romania. I tried restarting the phone, but it still works.

The problem appeared only on iOS 11, without and changes in code and from what I have tested, it is both in Swift and Objective-C.

This has caused an issue in my application. I could force the Locale to "en-US" and hope that it fixes the issue.

Has anyone else encountered this? Is there another way I could solve this issue?

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/16706425/1187415,  https://stackoverflow.com/q/40692378/1187415, https://stackoverflow.com/q/6613110/1187415, https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1480/_index.html – setting the locale to "en_US_POSIX" *is* the correct approach when parsing a fixed format.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion to use en_US_POSIX and I will try it. But what about why it worked after I switched the locale back and that it only happens on iOS 11?

Comment: You could also use current local: dateFormatter.locale = Locale.current

Comment: @RaduCarlig Referring this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46206511/7694178 I suppose your phone locale is something in `_RO` region and iOS11 `currentLocale` behavior forces it to `en_RO` using app's base language.  So the best choice for formatters now is forcing their locale as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Tried almost all the possible solutions I could find here but it still didn't work. 
So by some miracle I saw a comment that said ***"when converting a string to date, the string must exactly match the formatter description"*** and I change the format of the dateformatter to the date string and it worked.
hope this helps.